# Hibernate: deactivate the column version update for a specific save

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I know it's possible to completely deactivate the version by setting the version to false:

```
class Book {
    …
    static mapping = {
        version false
    }
}
```

But is it possible to deactivate it only for a specific case?

**Domain**

```
class Book {
    String author 
}
```

**Current behavior**

```
def BookInstance = Book.get(1)
println "version $BookInstance.version" //version 1
BookInstance.author = 'John'
BookInstance.save(flush:true) 
println "version $BookInstance.version" //version 2
```

**Specific case**

```
def BookInstance = Book.get(1)
println "version $BookInstance.version" //version 1
//Do something to deactivate the update version
BookInstance.author = 'John'
BookInstance.save(flush:true) 
println "version $BookInstance.version" //version 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen an option to disable temporarily optimistic locking.

If that's an option, you can execute a native update:

first inject the SessionFactory into the Service or Controller

```
def sessionFactory
```

then inside your method do something like this:

```
def sql = new Sql(sessionFactory.currentSession)
sql.execute("update BOOK set AUTHOR = 'john' where id = 1")
```

(I can't check the syntax right now, but it'll probably work)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look for [alternative locking](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch05.html) in hibernate:

> Your application is forbidden from altering the version number set by
>   Hibernate. To artificially increase the version number, see the
>   documentation for properties **LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT**
>   or **LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT** check in the Hibernate
>   Entity Manager reference documentation.
>
> If the version number is generated by the database, such as a trigger,
>   use the annotation **@org.hibernate.annotations.Generated(GenerationTime.ALWAYS)**.